# How to show by default Contributions Tab in Contact Summary Page?

Tags: civicontribute, contacts

If I want to access to a Contact Summary Page, I go to url:

```
http://<my_site>/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=<contact_id>
```

Is there any parameter I can add to url (or other way) where I can access to this Contact Summary Page but showing the Contributions Tab by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the parameter to set to url to show Contributions Tab by default (**force=1** & **selectedChild=contribute**):

```
http://<my_site>/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=<contact_id>&force=1&selectedChild=contribute
```

Answer (score 2):

With the most recent changes it's actually a lot easier. None of the solutions above worked for my situation (when someone clicks on a Contact they wanted Contributions tab to just appear).

With a little custom extension you can do this fairly easy

```
function wecancustom_civicrm_pageRun(&$page) {
  $pageName = get_class($page);

  // Switch the tab to Contributions
  if ($pageName == 'CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary') {
    CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()
    ->addSetting([
      'tabSettings' => ['active' => CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('selectedChild', 'contribute')],
    ]);
  }
}
```

This overrides the default. In our case, I did a bit more processing to determine if it was the proper Contact type we wanted with Apiv4.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CiviCRM allows this out of the box, but you can achieve this by following the below steps using JavaScript:

1. Using JavaScript check to see if the page url have '/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid='
2. Then set below two attributes in

   to true:

   `aria-selected="true"
    aria-expanded="true"`

   Where `id = tab_contribute`

Example:

`<li id="tab_contribute" class="crm-tab-button ui-corner-all livePage ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-tabs-active ui-state-active crm-count-1" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ui-id-23" aria-labelledby="ui-id-22" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">`

If your CMS is drupal, you can use [JS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector) module to include javascript which provides functionality to run JS on specific pages.

Let me know if you need more help.